# PHP - Traversing object fails if element's value is not of type STRING

Tags: php, json

I have this simple issue but, for the life of me, I can't figure out what's going on.
I have a JSON string that looks like the following:

```
{
"network_title": "Network",
"class_title": "Class",
"grades": [{
    "number": "Pre-K",
    "label": "Pre-Kindergarten",
    "order": 1,
    "id": "34567" 
}, {
    "number": "TK",
    "label": "Transitional Kindergarten",
    "order": 2,
    "id": "23456"
}, {
    "number": "K",
    "label": "Kindergarten",
    "order": 3,
    "id": "12345"
}]
}
```

It gets converted to an array like this (for specific reasons):

```
array:3 [
  "network_title" => "Network"
  "class_title" => "Class"
  "grades" => array:3 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "number" => "Pre-K"
      "label" => "Pre-Kindergarten"
      "order" => 1
      "gid" => "aa71da69-93ab-11e9-bda9-06f442b19d06"
    ]
    1 => array:4 [
      "number" => "TK"
      "label" => "Transitional Kindergarten"
      "order" => 2
      "gid" => "d3c6754a-6298-48d0-9afa-6a19bafb8464"
    ]
    2 => array:4 [
      "number" => "K"
      "label" => "Kindergarten"
      "order" => 3
      "gid" => "a815a771-9aff-4020-b7d2-0c95a05da21e"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I then try to loop through the array and when it finds an element that doesn't have a STRING type (like the `order` element), it fails with `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`
It shows the `foreach()` line as the offending one. Here's the code:

```
foreach ($arrTree as $k => $v)
    { 
        if (is_string($v)) 
        {
          //Do something here
        }
     }
```

I am sure I am missing something basic here but I am just tired of searching for the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `$arrTree` is a multi-dimensional array.

The foreach loop in your code only goes through the first level of the array, not the nested arrays (like "grades"). When it hits `"grades"`, the value `$v` is not a string, but an array, which is why the `is_string($v)` check fails.

You'll need to add a nested foreach loop to handle this structure.

**Here's an example how you can do this:**

```php
foreach ($arrTree as $k => $v)
{ 
    if (is_string($v)) 
    {
        //Do something here
    }
    else if (is_array($v))
    {
        foreach($v as $key => $value)
        {
            if(is_string($value))
            {
                //Do something here
            }
            else if(is_array($value))
            {
                foreach($value as $innerKey => $innerValue)
                {
                    if(is_string($innerValue))
                    {
                        //Do something here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, but I would need to know the depth of the data structure to know how many levels. Is there a more efficient method of doing it that would handle whatever the depth is? 
Also, why would the `foreach()` fail? I'm checking if it's a string. If it's not (like an array), it should skip it without failing.